# Executing a Python file from within Python, feeding it input and retrieving output

Tags: python, python-3.x, execution

I'm writing a web application where users may attempt to solve various programming problems. The user uploads an executable .py file and the application feeds it some pre-determined input and checks whether the output is correct. (similar to how [Codeforce](http://www.codeforces.com/problemset) works)

Assuming I have uploaded the user's script, how do I execute the user's script from within my own Python script, feeding the user's script input that would be captured by a normal `input()` function, and retrieving the output from `print()` functions so that I can verify its correctness?

Comment: What have you tried. Please make an effort to solve your problem before asking a question. More often then not, you'll end up solving your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

*Note*: If you are going to use this in a production environment, make sure you place restrictions on what the user can execute.

**executor.py**

```
import subprocess

# create process
process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['python3.4','script_to_execute.py'], # shell command
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

# encode string into bytes, since communicate function only accepts bytes
input_data = "Captured string".encode(encoding='UTF-8')

# send the input to the process, retrieve output of print() function
stdoutdata, stderrdata = process.communicate(input=input_data)

# decode output back into string
output_data = stdoutdata.decode(encoding='UTF-8')

print(output_data)
```

**script_to_execute.py**

```
input_data = input()

print("Input recieved!\nData: " + input_data)
```

**Output of executor.py**

```
Input recieved!
Data: Captured string
```

Comment: If you execute any script that somebody upload, you can count the seconds until your server will do something bad. You should at least start the subprocess in a restricted user account.

Comment: ... or a virtualenv.

Comment: If you pass `universal_newlines=True` to the `Popen` constructor, you can pass `str` and receive `str` without explicit encoding to `bytes` or decoding from `bytes`; `communicate` will take `str` as an argument, and return a two-tuple of `str`. Mind you, it uses the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, so on some machines (particularly Windows where it's usually something terrible like `cp1252` instead of `utf-8`), you may want to stick with explicit `encode` and `decode` steps.

Comment: @boardrider: `virtualenv` provides no security guarantees, it's just to provide a predictable separated environment for Python. Arbitrary user submitted code could effectively undo that virtualization, and even without undoing it, has no special restrictions on what it can do; if the user could do it outside a virtualenv, they can do it inside a virtualenv too.